# Rotating a canvas in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, jsfiddle

*First question as a new member*

I need help creating a rotate button. The js fiddle is for a ruler and I would like to be able to display the ruler horizontally and vertically. Currently the default is Horizontal. A user can rotate the ruler using the rotate controls but as a quick option I would like for them to be able to set the ruler to Horizontal. Ideally the numbers would also be displayed Vertically but this might be asking too much.

My js fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/cAslin/7ws41p8a/92/

Currently there is a rotate text field but I would like that removed and only the option of horizontal and vertical being and option. I want to retain the rotate option via the icons.

I would appreciate any help I could get on this as I have very little coding experience or knowledge.

Thank you!

```
<span id="draggable-element"><span style="margin-right:30px;" title="Drag  to rotate"><input id="clickable" class="click1" type="image" style="padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;transform: scaleX(-1);" src="https://s15.postimg.org/76smxbgmz/cycle.png"/></span>
```

Comment: A lot of words.. Shortly, do you need to rotate the ruler clicking on the control buttons?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the long winded explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ws41p8a/95/

I changed the target ID  `var target2 = $('#canvas');` in `rot` function. The ruler rotates

> If my answer helped, don't forget to mark it as correct